Where are the valid names for labels, column aliases etc documented for cypher queries (NEO4J)
I'm looking through the online documentation for what constitutes a valid cypher query label and column alias and not seeing a definitive description. In particular lots of examples I'm seeing show quoted alias columns and lables like foo but I don't see any reference that describes that or the general naming rules.
Does anyone know where this is specified?
References:
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/naming/
https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/openCypher9.pdf

Your question mentions "columns", but a graph has no tables and therefore no columns -- do you mean "properties"? Also, it is not clear what you mean by "alias".  Finally, you already provide a link to the naming rules doc, so it is not clear what you are really asking.

Column alias is the term used in the specs on https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/return/   that refers to   return a.foo as "bar"
But I'm also looking at node labels as well.   No where in that naming section does it specify you can use quotation marks but all the examples do so for both syntactical elements.

I don't see column aliases with double quotes on that page you linked (I assume that's what you meant as you wrote return a.foo as "bar"). They are not allowed in Cypher 5.

That seems to be an anomalous use of "column" in the Cypher docs. Also, be aware that opencypher is an "open source implementation" of a subset of Cypher, but is not the same as Cypher. If you are using neo4j, you should not be using opencypher docs as a reference.

Also, the doc section Using special characters in names tells you how to use special characters like quotes in names. For example, return a.foo as \"bar"``
